# Downloading canvas locally based on ID

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now and can't seem to, basically what I want to do is add an ID to a canvas which uses kinetic js, this works when I manipulate the code when inspecting the element. Does anyone have any ideas why this code does not apply an ID to my canvas, im not getting any errors;

```
 $(function() {
$('.kineticjs-content canvas').id = 'somename';
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Melissa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a layer, KineticJS actually creates 2 html canvases.

One canvas is used for hit-testing (internal use only).

One canvas is used to draw the Scene (this is what you want).

**To get a reference to the scene canvas and set its id, you can do this:**

```
var htmlCanvas = myLayer.getContext()._context.canvas;

htmlCanvas.id="gotcha";

console.log(htmlCanvas);
```

**[ Addition: a demo ]**

Here's example code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LmCgw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var myLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(myLayer);

    // get the Scene (html canvas) from KineticJS myLayer

    var htmlCanvas=myLayer.getContext()._context.canvas;

    // assign an id to that html canvas

    htmlCanvas.id="gotcha";


    // get a reference to the html canvas with id of "gotcha"

    var canvas=document.getElementById("gotcha");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw something on the regular html canvas (outside KineticJS)

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(100,100,20,0,Math.PI*2);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle="skyblue";
    context.strokeStyle="gray";
    context.lineWidth=3;
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark, im getting the error 'layer is not defined' which is the name of my layer, any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: I added an example for you to look at... :)

Comment: Mark this works great thank you for your time but I cannot seem to get it to work for mine, I would really appreciate if you had a sec to look at it, im sure its something silly. Thanks again http://jsfiddle.net/FT26S/

Comment: You're almost there: just change myLayer to layer ;)

Comment: How did I miss that? Its been a long day, I implemented it and don't get any errors although the id still doesn't apply :( Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hmmm...the id should be applying:  document.getElementById("gotcha") is fetching a reference to the canvas with id==gotcha

Comment: Turns out I was linking to an old library, however when I do that all the rest of my image download etc breaks. What a nightmare! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because the value returned by `$()` is a jQuery object, not an element.

You can access the individual elements from the jQuery object using the array access notation, so for your case, this should work:

```
$('.kineticjs-content canvas')[0].id = 'somename';
```

(alternatively using `$(...).attr('id', 'whatever')` should also work)

Comment: Hey Jani, Thanks for your help, When I do what you have suggested I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined.